# "being" or "as being"

Tags: grammar

Here

> 1. They are related to each other being the descendants of James.
> 2. They are related to each other as being the descendants of James.

In sentence no.1 "**being descendant of James**" is a participial phrase adding relation to two individuals, but the sentence sounds awkward to me, whereas the sentence no.2 sounds correct to my ears but I feel there is unnecessary repetition of "**as**" and "**being**"(we can use one of them).

I am no native speaker so, I could be wrong. The first one was used on family tree table or pedigree table which is a legal document.

Comment: [**To improve your question:**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: @whiskeychief I researched google books, but I didn't find any relevant suggestion. The problem is the participle phrase that is being used in first sentence doesn't sound correct to my ears but I can't prove it, and in second sentence it seems to be unnecessary usage of "as"

Comment: Decandant is not a word.

Comment: @Michael Harvey thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: They are related to each other **as** descendants of ABC. Or: as they are etc. or since they are etc. **being** is not needed here and is non-idiomatic.

Comment: ***Sorry!***. I missed the legal part. The answer is this for legal writing: ***They are related to each other, being descendants of X***. That is fine in legal language.  In non-legal language,it would not be used unless if were literary: Being descendants of X, their family always maintained the tradition.

Comment: @Lambie but without comma it doesn't make sense. Am I right?

Comment: They are related to each other, being the descendants of James. But in some old books, the comma may be missing due to handset type.

Answer (score 1):

They are related to each other, being the descendants of James.

They are related to each other as being the descendants of James.

The first sentence is absolutely grammatical.

You can use the present participle (the ing-form) to give a reason. For example:
She is  her father's favorite, being the youngest child = She is her father's favorite as/because she is the youngest child.

As for the second sentence, the use of "as" before being is redundant. So this sentence is not grammatical.